# A object was fired from ground with initial angle $\theta$

Tags: physics

so i got that , a object was fired from ground with angule  $ \theta $.
when the object get the height equal to half of his max height , the velocity of object is $\frac{3}{4}$ of initial velocity.Find the initial $\theta$ .
i Tryed this way

$$h_{1} = \frac{1}{2}h_{max}$$
$$V_{1} = \frac{3}{4}V_{0}$$
$$V_{1} = V_{0}.cos\theta_{1}  \Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}V_{0}= V_{0}.cos\theta_{1} \Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}=cos\theta_{1}$$
$$cos\theta_{1} \approx 48,49^{º}$$

but dont know how to move foward.

ps.sry for the bad english :/

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_0$ be the initial velocity. Then,
$$y=v_0\sin\theta t-\dfrac{1}{2}gt^2\\
y^\prime=v_0\sin\theta-gt=0\\
\implies t_{\mathrm{max}}=\dfrac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}\\
y_{\mathrm{max}}=v_0\sin\theta\dfrac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}-\dfrac{1}{2}g\left(\dfrac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}\right)^2=\dfrac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{2g}\\
\implies \dfrac{y_{\mathrm{max}}}{2}=\dfrac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{4g}\\
\dfrac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{4g}=v_0\sin\theta t_{\mathrm{max}/2}-\dfrac{1}{2}gt_{\mathrm{max}/2}^2$$
Solve for $t_{\mathrm{max}/2}$. Then use
$$v=\dfrac{3v_0}{4}=v_0-gt_{\mathrm{max}/2}\\
\implies t_{\mathrm{max}/2}=\dfrac{v_0}{4g}$$
Solve for $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall motion equations for a projectile: 
\begin{align}
x&=(v_0\cos \theta)t, & y&=(v_0\sin \theta)t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2\\
v_x&=v_0\cos\theta,&v_y&=v_0\sin\theta-gt
\end{align}
Maximun height is reached when $y'=0$, it is $t=\frac{v_0\sin\theta}{g}$ and $h_{\text{max}}=\frac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{2g}$. Let $t_1$ the time when $y=\frac{1}{2}h_{\text{max}}$, so
\begin{align}
(v_0\sin\theta)t_1-\frac{1}{2}gt_1^2=\frac{v_0^2\sin^2\theta}{4g}
\end{align}
Solving last equation we find two roots, namely $\frac{(2\pm \sqrt{2})v_0\sin\theta}{2g}$, what means there are two instants when $y=\frac{1}{2}h_{\text{max}}$, $t_1=\frac{(2- \sqrt{2})v_0\sin\theta}{2g}$, when projectile is going up, and $t_2=\frac{(2+ \sqrt{2})v_0\sin\theta}{2g}$, when projectile is going down. Then
\begin{align}
v&=\frac{3}{4}v_0\\
v_0^2\cos^2\theta+v_0^2\sin^2\theta-2(v_0\sin\theta)gt_1+g^2t_1^2&=\frac{9}{16}v_0^2\\
\end{align}
Reducing the last equation we get $7-8\sin^2\theta=0$ and then $\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{14}}{4}$.